# Google Contacts API asp.net settings and authorization token

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, google-api

Is there any good example that shows how to fill the application settings creating the settings for request?

this is code from [google](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/)

```
using Google.Contacts;
using Google.GData.Contacts;
using Google.GData.Client;
using Google.GData.Extensions;
// ...
    RequestSettings settings = new RequestSettings("<var>YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME</var>");
    // Add authorization token.
    // 
    // ...
    ContactsRequest cr = new ContactsRequest(settings);
```

Do I have to specify the token that I get from oAuth request, and no more?

The value for YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME could be any string value?

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample ? Maybe in github or codeplex

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use OAuth 2.0 you have to set `settings.OAuth2Parameters` to an instance of the `OAuth2Parameters` class or use the `RequestSettings(string applicationName, OAuth2Parameters parameters)` constructor.

The sample application at http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/browse/trunk/clients/cs/samples/oauth2_sample/oauth2demo.cs shows how to instantiate a `OAuth2Parameters` object.

Other `RequestSettings` constructors allow you to use OAuth 1.0 and other authentication mechanisms.